# Trying to parse JSON in Swift, but get error

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
{
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2016-09-23",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 1.4685,
        "BGN": 1.9558,
        "BRL": 3.5931,
        "CAD": 1.4625
    }
}
```

I got a json like this, and i tried to get the rates, but got the error, my code like:

```
let id = json["rates"] as? String
print("rates   :" + id!)
```

I am new to swifty, i want to get each rates separately, can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have try what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If let id = json["rates"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    print("rates   :" + id)
}
```

Comment: thanks, bro
Now, i can get
"AUD": 1.4685,
"BGN": 1.9558,
"BRL": 3.5931,
"CAD": 1.4625,

but how to get it separately? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below mentioned code to get the individual values.

Here the rate is a dictionary type, hence all values can be fetched by its corresponding key values (i.e AUD, BGN, etc like this `json["rates"]??["AUD"]`) as shown in my code.

**My Code :**

```
    let id = json["rates"]
    print("rates   : \(id)");

    print("AUD = \(json["rates"]??["AUD"])");
    print("BGN = \(json["rates"]??["BGN"])");
    print("BRL = \(json["rates"]??["BRL"])");
    print("CAD = \(json["rates"]??["CAD"])");
```

Hope it helps.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this too, it can give as many rates you have in your dictionary.

```
if let rates = json["rates"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

                for rate in rates {

                    let corresponsdingRate = rate.1 as? Float ?? 0.0
                    print("\(rate.0) = \(corresponsdingRate)")
                }
            }
```

Comment: @ccy1194021 Try out this one.